# Extracting whole words

Tags: python, regex, cpu-word, alphabetical, text-extraction

I have a large set of real-world text that I need to pull words out of to input into a spell checker. I'd like to extract as many *meaningful* words as possible without too much noise. I know there's plenty of regex ninjas around here, so hopefully someone can help me out.

Currently I'm extracting all alphabetical sequences with `'[a-z]+'`. This is an okay approximation, but it drags a lot of rubbish out with it.

**Ideally** I would like some regex (doesn't have to be pretty or efficient) that extracts all alphabetical sequences delimited by natural word separators (such as `[/-_,.: ]` etc.), and ignores any alphabetical sequences with illegal bounds.

However I'd also be happy to just be able to get all alphabetical sequences that ARE NOT adjacent to a number. So for instance `'pie21'` would NOT extract `'pie'`, but `'http://foo.com'` would extract `['http', 'foo', 'com']`.

I tried `lookahead` and `lookbehind` assertions, but they were applied per-character (so for example `re.findall('(?<!\d)[a-z]+(?!\d)', 'pie21')` would return `'pi'` when I want it to return nothing). I tried wrapping the alpha part as a term (`(?:[a-z]+)`) but it didn't help.

**More detail:** The data is an email database, so it's mostly plain English with normal numbers, but occasionally there's rubbish strings like `GIHQ4NWL0S5SCGBDD40ZXE5IDP13TYNEA` and `AC7A21C0` that I'd like to ignore completely. I'm assuming any alphabetical sequence with a number in it is rubbish.

Comment: Better use raw strings with regexes. `\d` happens to work, but other escape sequences will fail, and this can be hard to debug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you restrict yourself to ASCII letters, then use (with the `re.I` option set)

```
\b[a-z]+\b
```

`\b` is a word boundary anchor, matching only at the start and end of alphanumeric "words". So `\b[a-z]+\b` matches `pie`, but not `pie21` or `21pie`.

To also allow other non-ASCII letters, you can use something like this:

```
\b[^\W\d_]+\b
```

which also allows accented characters etc. You may need to set the `re.UNICODE` option, especially when using Python 2, in order to allow the `\w` shorthand to match non-ASCII letters.

`[^\W\d_]` as a negated character class allows any alphanumeric character except for digits and underscore.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I want, but I can't get the bally `\b`s to work. With `text` set as some normal sentence, `re.findall('\b[a-z]+\b', text, re.I)` returns nothing. No matter what I put in the square brackets (or using `search` or `match`) it doesn't seem to help either. Using `\B` gets me some results, but strips off the first and last character of each word. As lazy as it sounds I'm far too tired to pick up a new concept right now; any chance you know why it's not working? Or that you can post a literal example of how you'd use it in this case?

Comment: That's *exactly* why I wrote my comment to your question. If you don't use raw strings (`r"\b[a-z]\b"`), the `\b` will be interpreted as a backspace character.

Comment: Ooooooooooooh, that's what you meant :). Sorry, it's now 5:30am here and I was never going to make that connection. Simply add the r and it works a treat! Thank you, sir.

Comment: In general this works, but it will fail on words with special characters (e.g. `wenn bei Beförderungen Schäden`)

Comment: @yekta: Not if you compile the regex using the `re.UNICODE` or `re.LOCALE` option. I should add that to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you familiar with [word boundaries?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`). You can extract word's using the `\b` around the sequence and matching the alphabet within:

```
\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b
```

For instance, this will grab whole words but stop at tokens such as hyphens, periods, semi-colons, etc.

You can the `\b` sequence, and others, over at the [python manual](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

**EDIT** Also, if you're looking to about a number following or preceding the match, you can use a negative look-ahead/behind:

```
(?!\d)   # negative look-ahead for numbers
(?<!\d)  # negative look-behind for numbers
```

Comment: As per Tim's answer, `\b` sounds like what I want but it's not playing nice. Any ideas? I tried the lookahead and lookbehinds before but they seem to match all the characters right up until the character that is adjacent to a number, and so don't completely ignore words with numbers in them. Also it complains about lookaheads needing fixed-width patterns with those +s in there.

Comment: @Pie21: Then just use a single-digit match. We don't care how many numbers post/precede it, just that there's a digit. [example](http://re.dabase.com/webre.py?input=pie21+21pie+21pie21+pie&regex=\b%28%3F%3C!\d%29%28[a-zA-Z]%2B%29%28%3F!\d%29\b)

Comment: I got this working [   re.findall(r"\b([a-zA-Z]+)\b",content, re.I)    ] but it doesn't seem to weed out forward and back-slashes.  Here are some words that came out: '[endif]', '$', '8', '/small', '/li'

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
import re
yourString="pie 42 http://foo.com GIHQ4NWL0S5SCGBDD40ZXE5IDP13TYNEA  pie42"
filter (lambda x:re.match("^[a-zA-Z]+$",x),[x for x in set(re.split("[\s:/,.:]",yourString))])
```

Note that:

- split explodes your string into potential candidates => returns a list of "potential words"
- set makes unicity filtering => transforms the list in set, thus removing entries appearing more than once. This step is not mandatory.
- filter reduces the number of candidates : takes a list, applies a test function to each element, and returns a list of the element succeeding the test. In our case, the test function is "anonymous"
- lambda : anonymous function, taking an item and checking if it's a word (upper or lower letters only)

*EDIT* : added some explanations

Comment: Ugly as it is, it does work! Cheers! However can I ask one more favour: since I don't speak lambda OR filter, is there a way to do that kind of thing with `re.finditer()`? I need to keep track of the start and end indexes of each match in the text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code

```
print re.search(ur'(?u)ривет\b', ur'Привет')
print re.search(ur'(?u)\bривет\b', ur'Привет')
```

or

```
s = ur"abcd ААБВ"
import re
rx1 = re.compile(ur"(?u)АБВ")
rx2 = re.compile(ur"(?u)АБВ\b")
rx3 = re.compile(ur"(?u)\bАБВ\b")
print rx1.findall(s)
print rx2.findall(s)
print rx3.findall(s)
```