# How to extract words from a text using python?

Tags: python, split, words

I need to extract the words and phrases within a text. For example, the text is:

```
Привет, hello, как дела? english word, еще одно русское слово, слово-1224, тест 4456
```

And script should return the following:

```
Привет
как
дела
еще
одно
русское
слово
слово-1224
```

That is, I need to take from the text of all the words that begin with the Russian letters (`[а-яА-Яё-]`), and can contain numbers and letters of the Russian alphabet. How is this implemented?

Comment: I think you are talking about this,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717886/python-regex-extracting-whole-words

Regards.

Comment: It's a simple task with regular expressions. Just read up on how they work :)

Comment: Some of your words have a "-" in the middle, but you didn't mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a little bit trickier than I thought. Have never used cyrrilic chars. I do believe this should do:

```
text =  # Set you're input unicode string here.
words = re.findall('[\p{IsCyrillic}][0-9\p{IsCyrillic}]+', text)

for word in words:
    print word
```