# Create Python Dictionary from text file and retrieve count of each word

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary of words from a text file and then count the instance of each word and be able to search for a word in the dictionary and receive its count but I am at a stand still. I am having the most trouble making the text file words lowercase and removing their punctuation because otherwise my count will be off. Any suggestions?

```
f=open("C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\jefferson.txt","r")
wc={}
words = f.read().split()
count = 0
i = 0
for line in f: count += len(line.split())
for w in words: if i < count: words[i].translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() i += 1 else: i += 1 print words
for w in words: if w not in wc: wc[w] = 1 else: wc[w] += 1
print wc['states']
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

In Python, always use the following construct for reading files:

```
 with open('ls;df', 'r') as f:
     # rest of the statements
```

If you use `f.read().split()`, then it will read to the end of the file. After that you will need to go back to the beginning:

```
f.seek(0)
```

Third, the part where you do:

```
for w in words: 
    if i < count: 
        words[i].translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() 
        i += 1 
    else: 
        i += 1 
        print words
```

You dont need to keep a counter in Python. You can simply do ...

```
for i, w in enumerate(words): 
    if i < count: 
        words[i].translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() 
    else: 
        print words
```

However, you don't even need to check for `i < count` here... You can simply do:

```
words = [w.translate(None, string.punctuation).lower() for w in words]
```

Finally, if you just want to count `states` and not create an entire dictionary of items, consider using filter ....

```
print len(filter( lambda m: m == 'states', words ))
```

One last thing ...

If the file is large, it is inadvisable to put every word in memory at once. Consider updating the `wc` dictionary line by line. Instead of doing what you did, you can consider:

```
for line in f: 
    words = line.split()
    # rest of your code
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

with open('gettysburg.txt') as f:
    c = collections.Counter(f.read().split())

print "'Four' appears %d times"%c['Four']
print "'the' appears %d times"%c['the']
print "There are %d total words"%sum(c.values())
print "The 5 most common words are", c.most_common(5)
```

Result:

```
$ python foo.py 
'Four' appears 1 times
'the' appears 9 times
There are 267 total words
The 5 most common words are [('that', 10), ('the', 9), ('to', 8), ('we', 8), ('a', 7)]
```

---

Of course, this counts "liberty," and "this." as words (note the punctuation in the word). Also, it counts "The" and "the" as distinct words. Also, dealing with the file as a whole can be a lose on very large files.

Here is a version that ignores punctuation and case, and is more memory-efficient on large files.

```
import collections
import re

with open('gettysburg.txt') as f:
    c = collections.Counter(
        word.lower()
        for line in f
        for word in re.findall(r'\b[^\W\d_]+\b', line))

print "'Four' appears %d times"%c['Four']
print "'the' appears %d times"%c['the']
print "There are %d total words"%sum(c.values())
print "The 5 most common words are", c.most_common(5)
```

Result:

```
$ python foo.py 
'Four' appears 0 times
'the' appears 11 times
There are 271 total words
The 5 most common words are [('that', 13), ('the', 11), ('we', 10), ('to', 8), ('here', 8)]
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter
- [Extracting whole words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717886/extracting-whole-words)

Answer (score 0):

```
File_Name = 'file.txt'
counterDict={}

with open(File_Name,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
   # removing their punctuation
        words = line.replace('.','').replace('\'','').replace(',','').lower().split()
        for word in words:
            if word not in counterDict:
                counterDict[word] = 1
            else:
                counterDict[word] = counterDict[word] + 1

print('Count of the word > common< :: ',  counterDict.get('common',0))
```