# Python regex - Substring match

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern

```
pattern = "hello"
```

and a string

```
str = "good morning! hello helloworld"
```

I would like to search `pattern` in `str` such that the entire string is present as a word i.e it should not return substring `hello` in `helloworld`. If str does not contain `hello`, it should return False.

I am looking for a regex pattern.

Comment: I think you will find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717886/extracting-whole-words

Answer (score 3):

`\b` matches start or end of a word.

So the pattern would be `pattern = re.compile(r'\bhello\b')`

Assuming you are only looking for one match, `re.search()` returns None or a class type object (using `.group()` returns the exact string matched).

For multiple matches you need `re.findall()`. Returns a list of matches (empty list for no matches).

Full code:

```
import re

str1 = "good morning! hello helloworld"
str2 = ".hello"

pattern = re.compile(r'\bhello\b')

try:
    match = re.search(pattern, str1).group()
    print(match)
except AttributeError:
    print('No match')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use word boundaries around the pattern you are searching for if you are looking to use a regular expression for this task.

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern  = re.compile(r'\bhello\b', re.I)
>>> mystring = 'good morning! hello helloworld'
>>> bool(pattern.search(mystring))
True
```